# Find sum of subsequent 3 elements of an array

Tags: java

I need to sum the three consecutive elements of an array when appending numbers to the same array dynamically and return true if the sum is equal to the argument value. I have already written the code below and it all return required output but it fails for some test cases( I don't have the the exact test cases), Can anybody tell me what exact scenario which my programme can be failed?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    List<Integer> mergeList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    List<List<Integer>> allList = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> tail;
    int from = 0;
    int to = 0;

    public void addLast(int[] list) {
        allList.removeAll(allList);

        for(int i : list) {
            mergeList.add(i);
        }

        if (mergeList.size() > 0) {
            int j = 0;

            while(to < mergeList.size()){
                from = j;
                to = j + 3;
                tail = mergeList.subList(from, to);
                j++;
                allList.add(tail);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean containsSum3(int sum) {
        boolean retVal = false;
        
        for (List<Integer> sum3List : allList) {
            if (sum3List.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum() == sum) {
                retVal = true;
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test s = new Test();

        s.addLast(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
        System.out.println(s.containsSum3(6));
        System.out.println(s.containsSum3(9));

        s.addLast(new int[] { 4 });
        System.out.println(s.containsSum3(9));

        s.addLast(new int[] { 5, 2});
        System.out.println(s.containsSum3(11));
        
        s.addLast(new int[] { 0, -1 });
        System.out.println(s.containsSum3(7));
        System.out.println(s.containsSum3(2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
true
true
true
false
```

Comment: Here's an obvious one for you: if the first time you call `addLast` it is with an array with less than 3 elements then you will get a `IndexOutOfBounds` Exception.

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that. But it provides more than 3 elements.

Comment: How do you know the test cases provide more than 3 elements? The question says that you don't have the test scenarios.

Comment: " ( I don't have the the exact test cases) " Doesn't hurt to add in those edge cases that @sprinter mentioned... returning false when not enough elements are present is a good start to see if you pass testcases.

Comment: Hi @DennisLLopis, yes, I will handle his point and see. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generated large random collections of integers and couldn't find any obvious cases your code fails for beyond the insufficient elements. Incidentally, the function I wrote to check if a list has any consecutive n elements that sum to a given value was:

```
public static boolean containsSum(List<Integer> list, int sum, int n) {
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size() - n + 1)
            .anyMatch(i -> list.subList(i, i + n).stream()
                    .reduce(0, Integer::sum) == sum);
}
```

I can't see any reason for your code that keeps all the list of lists: the space / time tradeoff doesn't make a lot of sense. I suggest you could simplify `addLast` to just add the elements to `mergeList`. There are a bunch of stylistic issues with your code but I'm sure you'll work those out in your own time.

Comment: OP's code and yours obviously does not cover integer overflows

Comment: Excellent point. I'd be surprised if that's the failing tests but good pickup nonetheless